# copy dragged item

Tags: jquery, html

i have an list with images i can drag around.

To drag i use

```
 $('.test').draggable({opacity: 0.5}).resizable();
```

i want to copy the dragged div into the div it gets dragged in.
so if i drag

```
 <div class="test">
  <img src="test.png">
 </div>
```

into

```
  <div id="box">
  </div>
```

it should become

```
 <div id="box">
   <div id="test">
   <img src="test.png">
   </div>
 </div>
```

i want it in div box cause i'm gone print the div box. so if it isnt in div box but just over it, it wont print the img.

i can see its dropped useing

```
$('.box').droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
    .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
    .find( "p" )
    .html( "Dropped!" );
  }
});
```

Comment: $('.bord').droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
  .append(this)
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });   but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use, jquery ui draggable and droppable and use the helper clone, if you want to COPY content, if you want to move content just do an append on droppable, bye.

Comment: hi can you give an example of how i could use append

Comment: should be nice if you would actualy look at the question before downvoting it.

Comment: there´s an example on jqueryui page, you have to you .draggable .droppale. and droppable events, the helper goes in the .draggable item, bye.

Answer (score 0):

Inside

```
$("#bord").droppable
    ({  
        greedy: true,
        tolerance:"pointer",
        drop: function (event, ui) 
        {
             //here
        }
```

i have

```
        .addClass('sleep').appendTo($(this))
```

wich was all i needed.

Append did the trick for me.

Some information about Append.

[Link to jquery api examples](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.